# How to ensure user submitted numeric input follows a certain format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am working in PHP and I want to check if a given user submitted numeric input is not too big or too small.

- I am storing the amounts in the database as 64 bit integers (multiply them by 10^8 to avoid rounding errors in future calculations). I am limiting the amounts so that they cannot exceed the following precision: no more than 4 numbers after the decimal point. Also since the upper limit on user input should be 99 million, I also want to specify no more than 8 numbers precending the decimal point. How can I achieve this neatly?

My current approach seems a bit hack-ish:

Code:

```
//Check for existence of decimal point in string using strpos

//explode the string by the decimal point

//do a strlen on both the strings and check they dont exceed 8 and 4 respectively

//if no decimal point, simply do a strelen and check it's not greater than 8
```

- Also, I don't want the inputted data to be smaller than 0.0001. I am proficient in php for web design not familiar with the math functions of php is there an easy way to handle this?

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Sounds like you’re after the `preg_match` function and a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code below you can check whether the `$input` conforms to your requirements.
(See also this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/1OVByA)**.)

```
$input = ...;
$pattern = "~^\s*\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{1,4})?\s*$~";
if (($input > 0) && preg_match($pattern, $input)) {
    /* $input is OK */
} else {
    /* $input is NOT OK */
}
```

Requirements:

- `$input` has an integral part that is between 1 and 8 digits long.
- `$input` optionally contains a `.` followed by 1 to 4 digits (fractional part).
- `$input` is a positive number greater than or equal to 0.0001.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions and the `mb_ereg_match(regex,string)` function

Answer (score 0):

I think the following regex will match your needs.

It will match all numbers between 99999999.9999 and 00000000.0000 with and without the decimal point and also empty string.

The fractal part contains no more than 4 digits

```
if (preg_match('~^[0..9]{0,8}(?:\.[0..9]{1,4})?$~'), $number) {
  $match = TRUE;
} else{
  $match = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Note, it will also match an empty string. And the statement `It will match all numbers between 99999999.9999 and 00000000.0000` is somewhat inaccurate: you might want to add something like `with no more than 4 fractional digits` :)

Comment: The last part of my regex is doing the fractional digits matching
`(?:\.[0..9]{1,4})?`

Comment: I know your regex does it. Your description is inaccurate: You state `It will match all numbers between 99999999.9999 and 00000000.0000` (which includes 0.0000001). You should change the description to something like `It will match all numbers between 99999999.9999 and 00000000.0000 with no more than 4 fractional digits` (in order to more accurately describe what your regex (correctly) does).

Comment: Ok I understood it now and corrected it accordingly. Thank you @Expert System

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
if (preg_match('~^(?>[1-9]\d{0,7}+|0)(?>\.\d{0,3}+[1,9])?$~', trim($number), $result))
    // true
else
    // false
```

This pattern avoids things like `00015` or `1.000`, but if you want to allow this, just replace `[1-9]` by `\d` or better use `~^\d{1,8}+(?>\.\d{1,4}+)?$~` instead.

You must work after with $result which contain the trimed and verified number.

Answer (score -1):

See if this works:

```
$number = '123.4567';
if(preg_match('/^\s*\d*\.?\d{4}\s*$/', $number)) echo "Match";
else echo "Not match";
```

Comment: $price? Don't you mean $number?

Comment: This doesn't really takes all of the OP's requirements into account. Please, revise :)